# Changing only one object value of an array in setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change an X position of the image from one object in array. I want to change the position X in the state and then go through that state and make an image for each object.
I am getting undefined after I change the state on line 123.
[This is my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-haze-pqwfed?file=/src/Scene/M.js)

```
setImages(
          allImages.forEach((e) => {
            if (e.id === 1) {
              e.x += 10;
            }
          })
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
setImages(
  allImages.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.id === 1) {
      e.x += 10;
    }
  })
);
```

In this code `forEach` return undefined and you are modifying the state reference.

You should not modify state directly like `e.x += 10`

Instead you can use map to copy the array and spread syntax to copy the inner object

```js
setImages(
  allImages.map((image) => ({
    ...image,
    x: image.id === 1 ? image.x + 10 : image.x
  }))
);
```

You can also use previous react set state callback parameter

This doesn't cause infinite re render if you use it in `useEffect` hook

```js
setImages(prev =>
  prev.map((image) => ({
    ...image,
    x: image.id === 1 ? image.x + 10 : image.x
  }))
);
```

Comment: After setState I dont see any difference before drawing images. Am I able to see the difference on line 134 (I should have the object with differente x)? Also by some reason if you add more images and press move it will forget drwaing the last image from array

Comment: Can you fix all the missing dependencies in your effect. You can see the dependencies is wrong in code sandbox underlined yellow. Also react set state is aysnc. So you can't see it after you set it you can access it in the next render or via set state callback.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` method doesn't return anything, this is why you get undefined

whether there were values ​​or not, the forEach method always returns undefined. You need to rewrite setState on line 123 using map, creating new elements based on the old ones.

Comment: why is that? that state have values before setState

Comment: @devps whether there were values ​​or not, the forEach method always returns undefined.
You need to rewrite setState on line 123 using map, creating new elements based on the old ones.

Comment: By using map I get new array but of 4 undefined elements. I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34378814)

Comment: @Md.SukelAli Was it addressed to me?The solution is already written above, how does it differ from what I wrote?

Comment: @ViktorSuvorov check the last answer.